# Python - How to send base64 data from MongoDB to Multipart-form API

Tags: python, api, base64, multipartform-data

I have a MongoDB, where I have some small image sample stored as Base64.
My goal is to create a script in python, witch is able to read those and send a multipart/form request to an API.
This how API looks like on postman:
[image]

Actually this is my code in python:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import numpy as np
import cv2
import base64
import requests

def readb64(base64_string):
    sbuf = StringIO()
    sbuf.write(base64.b64decode(base64_string))
    pimg = Image.open(sbuf)
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pimg), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

client = MongoClient("mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017/")
mydb = client["image"]
mycol = mydb["samples"]
mydoc = mycol.find( { "api_shape_processed": False},
{ "_id": 1,"samples.eroded_sample_inverted_b64": 1}
)
url = 'http://localhost:8000/prediction/'
for x in mydoc:
  payload = {base64.b64decode(x)}
  files = {"foo": "bar"}
  response = requests.put(url, data=payload, file=files)
```

When I run it I receive this error message:

```
    raise TypeError("argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII "
TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'dict'
```

I'm missing how to create correct request to call correcly the API.
Thx in advance for any comments!

**UPDATE**

Using above query that's retrieved records:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5fe0d16baa01291a71c5bf55'), 'samples': [{'eroded_sample_inverted_b64': '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYFBgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoKCgoKBggLDAsKDAkKCgr........'}, {'eroded_sample_inverted_b64': '/9j/4AAQSkZJR.......}]}
```

If I use this sintax to generate the payload:

```
  for x in mydoc:
      payload = {base64.b64decode(x['samples']['eroded_sample_inverted_b64'])}
      print(payload)
```

I get this error:

```
payload = {base64.b64decode(x['samples']['eroded_sample_inverted_b64'])}       
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

**UPDATE2**
With this code:

```
url = 'http://localhost:8000/prediction/'

    for x in mydoc:
      for sample in x.get('samples', []):
        payload = {base64.b64decode(sample['eroded_sample_inverted_b64'])}
        nparr = np.fromstring(base64.b64decode(sample['eroded_sample_inverted_b64']), np.uint8)
        img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        files={"foo": "bar"}
        response = requests.post(url, data={'File': cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)}, files=files)
        print(response)
```

I obtain this error from the API side:

```
"POST /prediction/ HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

I don't really understand how to shape corretly the POST request.

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate the cursor using a `find()`, each document will be represented as a `dict` item; so you are passing the whole document to decode, rather than the specific field with the encoded data.

This might be closer to what you need:

```
for x in mydoc:
    payload = {base64.b64decode(x[samples][eroded_sample_inverted_b64])}
```

Comment: Even if I manually generate a B64 string from a retrieved image,  request fails: " raise ValueError("Data must not be a string.")
ValueError: Data must not be a string."

Answer (score 1):

`samples` is a list so you have to iterate that list; e.g.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import base64

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
b64 = base64.b64encode(b'test_string')

db.mycollection.insert_one({'samples': [{'eroded_sample_inverted_b64': b64}, {'eroded_sample_inverted_b64': b64}]})

for x in db.mycollection.find():
    for sample in x.get('samples', []):
          payload = {base64.b64decode(sample['eroded_sample_inverted_b64'])}
          print(payload)
```

prints:

```
{b'test_string'}
{b'test_string'}
```